# How to disable transparency for the project navigator?

Tags: xcode6, osx-yosemite, uiblureffect

I've updated to OSX Yosemite and see that one of the new "features" of Xcode is blur/transparency effect for the project navigator window. Below is an example of my wallpaper blurring through. I find this to be really fugly and distracting.

**Is there a way to disable this blur effect and get a flat/opaque Xcode 6 window?**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank the maker, why this is enabled by default in Xcode is beyond me

Comment: It's a design and stylistic choices of the entire OS, not just Xcode. Like asking why the navigation bar or notification center are translucent in iOS.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Open System Preferences > Accessibility > Display and select Reduce Transparency.

[image: sys-pref]

Comment: This changes the whole system's behavior. I like my terminal and other apps to be transparent :(